# meta_search NoMethodError when using fields_or_fields structure query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, meta-search

I am using meta_search. The following gives correct results:

```
User.search({:first_name_contains_any => ["peter", "john"]}).all
User.search({:last_name_contains_any => ["wong", "lee"]}).all
```

But the following does not work and throws NoMethodError:

```
User.search({:first_name_or_last_name_contains_any => ["peter", "something"]}).all
```

Does anyone has idea on it? Am I missing something..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot replicate this problem with meta_search 0.9.10. It works fine for me.